# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' Unable to spot error

Tags: python, django, implicit-conversion

My view.py looks as follows. I think the error is in this section. I will post a detailed function if this is not sufficient for now. Basically the model that takes total as argument is of type integer.

Edit 1: Writing the entire function so that it can be more helpful.

```
def subjManip(request):

    c= {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    subj = None
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SubjForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
               user = request.user
               subj1 = form.cleaned_data['subj1']
               subj2 = form.cleaned_data['subj2']
               subj3 = form.cleaned_data['subj3']

               if subj1 == None and subj2 == None:
                   raise forms.ValidationError("Both subjs cannot be empty")


               tot = float (((float(0.2017 * subj1 )+ float (0.09036 * subj2) + float(0.6309 * subj3) - 5.0269)/ 4.184)
               total =int(tot)

               elif subj1 == None:
                   total = subj1
```

Comment: [pep8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) - Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or `is not`, never the equality operators.

Comment: Pretty sure that the problem is not in this section of the code: the only `int` call always gets a `float` instance and that's fine. It might be in the `SubjForm` instantiation though. Can you post the whole exception/backtrace.

Comment: @Michael you were right. In the form, I had mistakenly declared subj3 as character instead of integer. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `tot = (subj1+subj2)/2.2` with `tot = (float(subj1) + float(subj2)) / 2.2`

Comment: Then posting a detailed function might help.

Comment: @Ngenator I found out the error was in the form where I had wrongly specified the subj3 value to be integer.